# What does it mean by Object.assign(fn, {x: () => {}, y: () => {}})?

Tags: javascript

Let's I have a function defined as below,

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const calculateHash = cache({ ttl: 5, size: 100 }, async file_path => {
    const buffer = await fs.readFile(file_path);
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(buffer).digest('base64');
});

const cache = (options, fn) => {
  return Object.assign(fn, {
    cache_size: () => {
       return 0;
    },
    clear_cache: () => {
      // clear_cache is not implemented
    },
  });
};
```

When I do `console.log(calculateHash())`, it logs as,

```
[AsyncFunction (anonymous)] {
  cache_size: [Function: cache_size],
  clear_cache: [Function: clear_cache]
}
```

...and when I do,

```
async function run() {
  const cache1 = await calculateHash('./fileToCache.js');
  console.log(cache1)
}

run()
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

It actually calls the async function.

```
EB26xyw+zvLiccSc9Y3ZPDP0qqpBnNQsXdwyIFk8wPY=
done
```

**How does it work here?**

*When I do `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`, it will merge them; if properties are same it will override.*

So, I think here `Object.assign()` creates a final object as below

```
{

  [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  cache_size: [Function: cache_size],
  clear_cache: [Function: clear_cache]
}
```

**But on calling `calculateHash()`, how does it know to call the first property?**

Comment: *"how does it know to call the first property?"*: how do you know the first property got called? BTW, the expression in the title is not valid JS. You forgot a property name "y"`.

Comment: Fixed the title. When I call `calculateHash('src/index.js)` it actually calls the async function.

Comment: How have you confirmed that the async function is called? Can you edit your question and include a runnable snippet (using toolbar) that proves that?

Comment: I have added another code to run it, but I don't think I can pass an actual file as an argument in the code snippet using the toolbar.

Comment: You write *"It actually calls the async function"*. Above you have 2 async functions, one anonymous, one called `run`. `run` is executed, but that anonymous one is not. If you believe it is different, please provide code with which we can reproduce some specific output that proves that the function is *called*. The output you have included in the question does not prove the execution of the anonymous async function, as it just displays the function object. There is not trace of an execution of it.

Comment: Is the implementation of `cache` just an example? The question is motivated by the lack of the `options` parameter in the implementation.

Comment: @trincot It's perfectly runnable, just try at least once running it. ..and both functions are executed: _anonymous async_ and _run_

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, wanted example to be only what I was asking rather than creating confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions *are* objects, and `Object.assign` mutates it's first argument and returns it:

```js
const foo = {};
const bar = Object.assign(foo, { hi: 5 });
foo.hi; // 5
bar.hi; // 5
foo === bar; // true, foo and bar are the *same* object
```

If you do

```js
const add3 = Object.assign(function(n) { return n + 3 }, { someValue: 42 });

add3(5); // 8
add3.someValue; // 42
```

Then `add3` is still a function. You're being led astray by what the console is showing you, that async anonymous function isn't a *property* of the resulting object, it *is* the resulting object, with some stuff added to it. Note that "property" is in square brackets, and there's no *name* associated with it.

Comment: Yep, the console is messing. It just attaches those two methods: `clear_cache()` and `clear_cache()` as it's properties as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to access added properties inside the anonymous async function?

Comment: @confusedWarrior not normally, if it's an arrow function `this` will be the value of `this` in the enclosing scope, if it's a `function` function then `this` will be set by the context it's called in, `this` won't ever refer to the function object itself. You could do it by using a named function that references itself by name: `const f = (n) => f.value + n; Object.assign(f, { value: 2 }); console.log(f(3));` will log 5.